# MySQL- Insert a record with empty primary key, works on one server, not the other

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, insert-update, string

I have a table in a MySQL Server (version 5.5.27, installed with EasyPHP for development), it has an ID with Auto_Increment, and it's data type is INT(11).

When i try to insert a record, using this statement, it works.

```
insert into factclientes (IDFactClientes, IDTercero, SubTotal, IVA, Total)
        values ('', '3', '2500.00', '400.00', '2900.00')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IDTercero = values(IDTercero),
                SubTotal = values(SubTotal), 
                IVA = values(IVA), 
                Total = values(Total)
```

But when i try to insert that same record on my production server (version 5.6.17, installed independently on another machine) it throws an error:

```
 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'IDFactClientes' at row 1
```

I know it is because the primary key ID 'IDFactClientes' has an empty value.  I do this because i use the same statement to INSERT and to UPDATE. If my program doesn't know and doesn't specify the IDFactClientes, i want a new record, if my program knows the ID already, and it's specified i want the record to be updated.

The weird thing is that it works on my dev machine, but it doesn't on my production server.

Is there a setting im missing?? how could i fix this??  i have the exact same problem with all the tables of my database and i wouldn't want to modify all the statements in my program... if it's possible

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Are the defaults set to NULL on both machines? if you insist on supplying the key but want it forced as auto increment, set the column to "NOT NULL" and supply NULL as a value.  alternatively use the value 0.   '' is not an integer and cannot be used for the column

Comment: ID is set to Null - NO , and Default - none, in both servers. Can NULL or 0 be in between single quotes? or just the value?   I'll give it a try!! thanks!!

Comment: without quotes. quotes signal a string or character value. try NULL or leave the column out completely, both should work according to mysql's auto_increment documentation

Comment: Thanks!!! the thing is that if i change that i would have to edit all my files, and it will take some time to add the variable to be null or 0, i want to leave that as a last resource, do you think there's a setting to "allow" the server to receive an empty primary key?, it would be much faster to just change the settings if there's one

Comment: the DEFAULT NULL  and NULLABLE: NO  usually does the trick, but then you have to remove it from the column. I don't know of any way for '' to be accepted as a valid integer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it!!! or remembered it... a while ago i heard something about "STRICT MODE",   and i suddenly remembered about it!!   so i looked for how to turn off the "strict mode" and i found two methods:

Method 1:
Open the "my.ini" file within the MySQL installation directory and look for something like...

```
# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Replace with:

```
# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Method 2:
You may be able to run an SQL query within your database management tool such as phpMyAdmin which can normally be found from your web hosting control panel:

```
SET @@global.sql_mode= '';
```

I Think the first method is permanent, and the second one has to be done every connection... i think